# Identifying pin 1 of Analog Devices REF195

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages, pinout

I have the [Analog Devices REF195GSZ](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ref195.html), and it doesn't have a circle on either the top or bottom by a pin to indicate pin 1.

Looks like this:

[image: Photo of Analog Devices REF195 top surface]

Which is pin 1? The datasheet didn't seem to help either: *[Analog Devices - Precision Micropower, Low Dropout Voltage References, Data Sheet. REF19x Series](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/REF19XSERIES.pdf)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One edge of the package is beveled. Pin 1 is on the beveled side.

[image]

Comment: damn, thanks! don't understand why manufacturers don't always put a circle smh. will accept the answer once the 7 min is up

Comment: And that weird dimple, which I've never seen.

Comment: well it is installed and works, so just confirming this was indeed correct.

Answer (score 7):

Three is a notch/gap near the left bottom pin (next to the P of P1744). This is pin 1.

Then pins are always counted counterclockwise, so the pin numbers are:

```
Pin numbers: 8 7 6 5
Text on IC:  REF195
Text on IC:  >G#031
Text on IC:  P1744
Pin numbers: 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides the beveled edge and notch mentioned in the other answers, if you hold the part so the text is right-side-up, pin 1 is at the bottom left.

Comment: yup makes sense!

Comment: This is definitely not a fool proof method. Most often you'll be fine with this, but it's not *always* the case in general.